# Scala Parsing a large XML element

Tags: xml, scala

In Scala I'm attempting to parse a large XML element with following format:

> `<position>`
>  
>   0.68 0.37 0.07
>   0.68 0.37 0.07
>   0.68 0.37 0.07
>   ...
>   ...
>   `<\position>`

I'd like to break each line of this element into a tuple (perhaps) of type double, and add each tuple to a container. The code I have so far:

```
val sample = scala.xml.XML.loadFile("filename.xml")
(sample \ "position")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way in my opinion is

```
(sample \ "position").text.trim.split('\n')
  .map(_.split(" ").map(_.toDouble))
  .map(x => (x(0), x(1), x(2)))
```

Comment: This will not work for really large XML files, as the XML library uses a DOM parser. You either have to read the whole XML as a String and use the tequniques directly as described in the answer above or switch to a SAX or Pull Parser.